Testing Puzzles for Puzzle Book: Enigmatic Puzzle
Here's a puzzle that I'm working on currently. Would love to see if folks can solve. The final answer is a word/phrase. Thanks!
RLLCLL
Have I accounted for all those who aren't present?
SVNTHHVN
NRMDBNDT
KLLTWBRDSWTHNSTN
THTHRSTGS
SXDGRSFSPRTN
HGHFV
THFRHRSMNFTHPCLPS

Is there a final word at the end? I think I got all the items

Yes, the final answer should be a word or phrase.

Continuing from Lukas's near miss:

 A ROLL CALL reveals that all vowels have gone missing. Let's see:

 SEVENTH HEAVEN (5 vowels missing)
ONE ARMED BANDIT (6 missing)
 KILL TWO BIRDS WITH ONE STONE (8 missing)
 THE THREE STOOGES (6 missing)
 SIX DEGREES OF SEPARATION (10 missing)
 HIGH FIVE (3 missing)
 THE FOUR HORSEMEN OF THE APOCALYPSE (13 missing)

 The answer is a word or phrase. It is deceptive to use the numbers in the solutions for extracting letters or for sorting. It turns out that the numbers in the answers are just a way of confirmation. For the final answer, the number of missing vowels in each phrase are used: If there are m missing vowels in a phrase, take its m-th letter.

 This yields NMBRSGM, which we can vowel-expand to NUMBERS GAME.


Incorrect answer. I'll leave it here because it's a happy coincidence

I think the answer might be

 Eight Off

Explanation:

 Each line is a phrase with missing vowels. (RLLCLL = Roll Call)
 SVNTHHVN = Seventh Heaven
 NRMDBNDT = One-armed bandit
 KLLTWBRDSWTHNSTN = Kill two birds with one stone
 THTHRSTGS = The Three Stooges
 SXDGRSFSPRTN = Six degrees of separation
 HGHFV = High five
 THFRHRSMNFTHPCLPS = The four horsemen of the apocalypse

Now notice that

 Each phrase contains a number inside of it. "Two birds with one stone" contains two numbers, but we only care about the first one so we get the numbers 1-7, once each. Now take the nth letter of each completed phrase, you get hoiegff

Naturally we try

 The find the next number, 8. hoiegff contains eigh with a missing T, and the remaining letters spell off. Given the question Have I accounted for all those who aren't present?, I think the answer is no, you "forgot" about the 8th phrase (which would've given us the T), to complete the final answer Eight Off!


I tried indexing the letters then solve the anagram but the missing ‘T’ and the two ffs made me doubt my method

I couldn't make anything work with vnltsvr or nltrvsv (original phrases) and inserting vowels again, so I figured it has to be this, even with the rearranging and missing letter.

Unfortunately, that's not quite right, though perhaps better than what's intended! The phrases are all correct, but the extraction step you used isn't the intended method (it would be great if it corresponded to the number from each clue, but it's actually corresponding to something else that the tagline suggests)
